# ?ACT not working anymore after upgrade from ExpressionEngine 2.2.1 to ExpressionEngine 2.5.3

Tags: expressionengine

I am completely stuck as to why my EE install after the upgrade to EE 2.5.3 suddenly does not allow for some standard ?ACT eg search (?ACT=2), sending off a contact form or logout (?ACT=10) from the front end.

Actions get redirected to the homepage.

No additional modules installed after upgrade.

my htaccess file includes just a basic redirect

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]
```

Cheers

Comment: Just to rule out any possibility that the .htaccess is at fault, do the ACT urls work if you remove the .htaccess and access the script with the actual URL? Ex: http://your-domain.com/index.php?ACT=X (The markdown parser is converting my string to a link, but there is suppose to be an "http://" before the domain.)

Comment: Justin- just put backticks around things to avoid them turning into links :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably have the following in your .htaccess instead - this is likely to be the cause.

`RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1 [L]`

Replace your line :

`RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L]`

with the above and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

Usually have these three lines in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(ACT=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(URL=.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```